# How to determine encoding of an ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java

I need to convert `ByteArrayOutputStream`  to `String` but I can't figure out the encoding. Please help ? I tried Using `ICUJ` library but It only works for input stream. A conversion from byte array to input stream is also fine.

Here's a sample of what I'm getting using the default encoding. Clearly the new lines are not supposed be there.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n
<html>
   \n   
   <head>
      \n        
      <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">
      \n            
      <style type=\"text/css\">\n                   .style_0 { font-family: sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; color: black; text-indent: 0em; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: normal; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; line-height: normal;}\n                    .style_1 { height: 5.062in; width: 8.01in;}\n           </style>
      \n            <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n          //<![CDATA[\n             function redirect(target, url){\n                   if (target =='_blank'){\n                       open(url);\n                }\n                 else if (target == '_top'){\n                       window.top.location.href=url;\n                 }\n                 else if (target == '_parent'){\n                    location.href=url;\n                }\n                 else if (target == '_self'){\n                      location.href =url;\n                   }\n                 else{\n                     open(url);\n                }\n                }\n            //]]>\n            </script>\n     
   </head>
   \n       <body class=\"style_0\" style=\" margin:0px;\">\n           <table cellpadding=\"0\" style=\"empty-cells: show; border-collapse:collapse; width:8in; overflow: hidden; table-layout:fixed;\">\n             
   <col>
   </col>\n             
   <tr>
      \n                    
      <td></td>
      \n                
   </tr>
   \n               
   <tr>
      \n                    
      <td valign=\"top\"></td>
      \n                
   </tr>
   \n               
   <tr>
      \n                    
      <td>
         \n                     
         <div style=\"overflow:hidden; height:0.5in\">\n                            <div style=\" overflow:hidden;\">Dec 23, 2013, 7:11 PM</div>
         \n                     </div>\n                    
      </td>
      \n                
   </tr>
   \n           </table>\n              
   <hr style=\"color:red\"/>
   \n               
   <div style=\"color:red\">
   \n                   
   <div>The following items have errors:\n          </div>
   \n           <br>\n                      
   <div>
   \n                           
   <div  id=\"error_title\" style=\"text-decoration:underline\">
   Chart (id = 12):
```

\n

Comment: I'm not asking you to magically guess the encoding. I know libraries exists for figuring out encodings for `InputStream` so there's surely a programatical way to figure it out. If you can't help , please refrain from posting useless comments

Comment: If ICU4J can do what you want, then simply turn the `BAOS` into a `BAIS`.

Comment: BTW No, there isn't an automatic way to figure out the text encoding. The best you can hope for is a flaky heuristic.

Comment: Not intending to be snarky, but the encoding should be documented somewhere if this is coming from a documented API (eg, if it's JSON it's by definition UTF8), and if it's your own code you should be able to see where the stream is generated and figure it out.

Comment: The encoding I'm trying to figure out is of BIRT reporting output stream which is basically outputting HTML tags. Any idea which encoding is commonly used for this? I tried Utf-8

Comment: And what happened with your attempt? What did you get?

Comment: I got the output but I could find some random characters in it like `\n` `\r` along with the html which shouldn't have existed

Comment: `\n` and `\r` are not exactly random characters. They are newlines. If everything else was correct, then you don't have an encoding issue at all.

Comment: I did post what I thought was important. The reason I didn't post more is 'cus I'm new and I cant really make out what would help in diagnosing the issue. That's why I came here for help . If I knew to ask the right question , I would have googled it and found it out.

Comment: :| check of the update . I heard when the encoding is not known java uses default characters to replace unknown characters which I feel is happening .

Comment: What is still unclear is how exactly you gererated that output, but one thing is for sure: your problem is not the `byte[]`->`String` decoding. The literal characters `'\'`, `'n'` etc. may have been in the byte stream, or they may have been introduced at a later stage.

Comment: What you heard about "default characters" pertains to *encoding*: when the target charset doesn't contain a character from the string being encoded, a `?` is emitted (by default).

Comment: Hm...alright..For now I managed to replace the `\n\r` and got it working.

Comment: Cool... you did it within Java, with `replace("\\n","")`? In that case it's 100% clear: these literal characters (a backslash followed by the letter `n` or `r`) are present in the byte array which you are decoding.

Comment: Hm yea I did it in Java. Maybe its a fault with BIRT or I didn't set some flag. Anyways , thanks.

Comment: The newlines are probably there because they were there in the original source.  But the source was run through several transformations (unrelated to code page), one which converted control characters to their escape character equivalents, and another which reformatted the code, reinserting the "missing" control characters.

Answer (score 4):

> I tried Using ICUJ library but It only works for input stream.

You can get the byte array from the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and then wrap it in a `ByteArrayInputStream` ... and pass *that* to the ICUJ method.

---

(Bear in mind that there is a chance that ICUJ will intuit the wrong encoding.  Or that the bytes might not represent text in any known encoding.)

Answer (score 1):

It won't much help but java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder has a `detectedCharset()` method to auto identify charset of character encoded bytes. But unfortunately current impl of CharSetDecoder in Java SE7 (the one that is received by calling the method `Charset.newDecoder()`) is not an auto detecting charset decoder so calling `detectedCharSet()` method throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.